# Running ipython notebook on Debian

Tags: python

I'm trying to get ipython notebook to run on my Debian machine without much success.  I've installed ipython and ipython-notebook via apt-get, but when I try to start it up I get the following:

```
$ ipython notebook
Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook
$ dpkg -l ipython ipython-notebook
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                          Version             Architecture        Description
+++-=============================-===================-===================-===============================================================
ii  ipython                       1.2.1-2             all                 enhanced interactive Python shell
ii  ipython-notebook              1.2.1-2             all                 interactive Python html notebook
$ ipython --debug notebook        
[TerminalIPythonApp] Config changed:
[TerminalIPythonApp] {'TerminalIPythonApp': {'log_level': 10}}
[TerminalIPythonApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/eyal/.config/ipython/profile_default'
[TerminalIPythonApp] Searching path [u'/home/eyal', u'/home/eyal/.config/ipython/profile_default'] for config files
[TerminalIPythonApp] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
[TerminalIPythonApp] Config file ipython_config.py not found

[TerminalIPythonApp] Loading IPython extensions...
[TerminalIPythonApp] Loading IPython extension: storemagic
[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | File not found: u'notebook'
[TerminalIPythonApp] IPython not interactive...
$ dlocate ipython_config.py   
ipython: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-  packages/IPython/config/profile/math/ipython_config.py
ipython: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/profile/pysh/ipython_config.py
ipython: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/profile/sympy/ipython_config.py
ipython: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/config/profile/cluster/ipython_config.py
```

Note sure where it's looking for notebook or why it's not finding it.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a reason you are running it using "sudo"?

Comment: What Debian version, please? Please list `dpkg -l ipython ipython-notebook`.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the dpkg command in my original post.  I'm using a Debian derivative called Siduction.  It's basically Debian's Sid branch.  Thank you

Comment: @oneself if you want someone to see your comment, you need to prefix it with a @ username.

Comment: @oneself To start with it is complaining about not finding `ipython_config.py`. However, this is in the ipython package. If you have dlocate installed then do `dlocate ipython_config.py`. Otherwise `dpkg -S ipython_config.py`. And post the results in the question. Incidentally, any specific reason you are using an obscure Debian derivative?

Comment: I'm getting: `$ ipython notebook
[NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/faheem/.config/ipython/profile_default'
[NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from /home/faheem
[NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
[NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels.` This is on wheezy with the ipyhon wheezy packages.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: I've switched back to Ubuntu.  Still getting the same problem. I've updated my question with the output of dlocate.

Comment: @oneself that's really odd. the problem is following you across distributions? is there anything in common?

Comment: Incidentally, `dlocate ipython_config.py` gives me 12 hits. This is with ipython and ipython-notebook 0.13.1-2 on Debian wheezy. Can you update dpkg -l output on Ubuntu? Also, is the dlocate output for Ubuntu?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I've update dpkg -l output when I did the others.  What's the same is my home dir.  I kept it across installations (/home is on a different partition).  I've tried removing ~/.ipython, but that doesn't help either.  Is there anything else I might need to delete?

Comment: OK. Suggestion: Try a different installation of your system in a completely different location, and this time don't use your home directory. Perhaps you can use a chroot. I'd try both Ubuntu and Debian wheezy if you have the time to spare. I can't reproduce the problem with wheezy, and in any case wheezy is generally relatively bug free. Ubuntu is less bug free but it is still surprising to see a package completely broken with no reason. What Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Using the latest Ubuntu version 14.04.

Comment: Ok. If you think it will help, we can talk in chat, but I suggest you first try what I suggested. I generally prefer the main chat room because there are other people there who may occasionally take a interest.

Answer (score 1):

Have you, by any chance, installed another version of iPython (for example, through Pip)?

What is the result of `type ipython` on your system. If that's something else than `ipython is /usr/bin/ipython` (or an equivalent in your locale, of course), try to run `/usr/bin/ipython notebook`.

Comment: Hi, I've since abandoned using notebook, but have recently tried installing it again, and this time it just worked.  So, I'm not sure what was the problem.

Comment: Since `ipython-notebook` was installed (as you checked with `dpkg`) and `ipython` claimed it was not, I can only see two options: either part of `ipython-notebook` has been removed without removing the package, or you had two different versions of `ipython` and was not using the one installed via the `ipython` package.

Answer (score 0):

First, why are you running with `sudo`?

Try running it as `ipython notebook --debug` (i.e. the `--debug` parameter in the end), it works for me in Debian testing.

Comment: Sorry, I tried sudo on one occasion just to make sure it was not a permissions problem.  When I run "ipython notebook --debug" I just get "Could not start notebook. Please install ipython-notebook" with not debug info.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have ipython notebook installed. Try `apt-cache search ipython-notebook` to see if you can install it.